# How to access variables in another package in java?

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

I am trying to access variables in another package in java, I tried some code:

The first package contains two classes, this is the first one

```
package encapsuation;
import s2.foo;

public class Encapsulation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        s1 a = new s1();
        a.age = 21;
        a.name = "ahmed";

        a.print();
        foo.print();
    }

}
```

The second one, this is what I need to access in the class of the second package.

```
package encapsuation;

public class s1 {
    public  static String name;
    public static int age;

    public static void print()
    {
        System.out.println(name + " " + age);    
    }
}
```

The second package contain one class

```
package s2;
import encapsuation.s1;

public class foo{

    public static void print()
    {
        System.out.println(s1.name + " " + s1.age);    
    }

}
```

Is what I am trying correct?

And why I cannot access the variables in class of the second package in the class "public class foo" but can access them in the method print only?

Comment: Any specific reason why you made `name` and `age` static? (and the `print()` method not static)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking and your code is a mess, does it even compile? And try to follow java naming practices, it makes it so much easier for us that tries to read your code, class names should start with an upper case letter so Foo and S1 and also use more meaningful names for classes and variables than `s1` and `a`

Comment: I have edit the code and make the method static

Comment: I just need explanation for my question

Comment: The class `foo` *can* access those static members of `s1`.
The code given would not compile, because `foo` is misspelt as `fue` in `main`. If this was corrected, the output would be "ahmed 21" twice.

Comment: What do you really mean by `why I cannot access the variables in class of the second package in the class "public class foo"`? By saying access the variables `in class of the second package`, you meant Member Variables right?  And by saying `but can access them in the method print only`, which print are you refering, the one in the 1st or 2nd package? I really don't get it. Your question needs more clarification.

Comment: Study a tutorial before posting here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
public class foo{
    String s = s1.name; 
    public static void print()
    {
        System.out.println(s1.name + " " + s1.age);    
    }

}
```